# Can bone mineral be obtained in pure, crystalline form?

Tags: biochemistry, crystal-structure

Can bone mineral be obtained in pure, crystalline form outside a living organism? Had this been done ever?

Comment: What do you mean by bone mineral? Its calcium carbonate / phosphate content?

Comment: Bone has a complex structure and formation. There has been studies which shows a relationship between the formation of the "mineral" ie hydroxyapatite  and protein (collegen). I doubt that any materials similar to bone is seen outside a living organism (except exoskeleton)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apatite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apatite) is the chemical name for the mineral found in bone and teeth. It is occasionally found in the form of large crystals, such as this:

[image]

BTW, just as bone is made of the mineral apatite, there are critters with skeletons of *silica*, another common mineral, such as [Venus' flower basket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus%27_flower_basket)!

Comment: Thank you. I have already found that bones are mostly built from hydroxylapatite [img]https://www.mineralauctions.com/public/multimedia/images/auctions/items/thumbs/111506_465xV.jpg [/img] It is mostly mined but also used in medicine for prosthetics.